# /home/user/.Private 100% disk usage?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, diskspace

Came into work this morning to find out that my disk is full. I have a total of 16TB's of storage and am using less then 1TB (in total) of data.

While looking into this I realized that I have encrypted my home drives, which is cool and all, but it seems that `ecryptfs` is displaying a lot of storage space.

Looking into this I found the following [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-utils/+bug/444282) report about how the data is displayed incorrectly. Looking further into my `inodes`, and my data I come up with the following information:

```
admin@magic:~$ df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1.6G  9.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/Magic--vg-root  2.7T  2.7T     0 100% /
tmpfs                            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda2                        473M   94M  355M  21% /boot
/dev/sda1                        511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
/home/admin/.Private       2.7T  2.7T     0 100% /home/admin
tmpfs                            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
admin@magic:~$ sudo df
Filesystem                       1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                               7961968          0   7961968   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1594416       9904   1584512   1% /run
/dev/mapper/Magic--vg-root 2882509120 2882207660         0 100% /
tmpfs                              7972064          0   7972064   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 5120          0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7972064          0   7972064   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                              7972064          0   7972064   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda2                           483946      96062    362899  21% /boot
/dev/sda1                           523248       3436    519812   1% /boot/efi
/home/admin/.Private      2882509120 2882207660         0 100% /home/admin
tmpfs                              1594416          0   1594416   0% /run/user/1000
admin@magic:~$ df -i
Filesystem                         Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                              1990492    487   1990005    1% /dev
tmpfs                             1993016    841   1992175    1% /run
/dev/mapper/Magic--vg-root 183042048 217865 182824183    1% /
tmpfs                             1993016      1   1993015    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             1993016      4   1993012    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                             1993016     16   1993000    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                             1993016      1   1993015    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2                          124928    300    124628    1% /boot
/dev/sda1                               0      0         0     - /boot/efi
/home/admin/.Private            183042048 217865 182824183    1% /home/admin
tmpfs                             1993016      4   1993012    1% /run/user/1000
admin@magic:~$ sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G|T"
11M /etc
2.4G    /usr
14M /sbin
9.9G    /home
1.2G    /var
395G    /srv
554M    /lib
95M /boot
2.3T    /mnt
9.8M    /run
16M /bin
2.7T    /
2.7T    total
admin@magic:~$
```

Please note that `/mnt` is a complete separate hard drive that is used for storage and backups that is mounted on the filesystem

How can I figure out what is taking up all of my data, and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Disk Usage Analyzer called baobab has never failed me on such a simple thing, maybe you should give it a shot.